# android basic sqlite update statement error

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to update only address and phone in sqlite. How can i solve the db.update?

My KEY_ID always is 1 because im only having one row in database

```
public void updatecontact(String address, String phone){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
    values.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);

    String userid="1";
    return db.update(TABLE_LOGIN, values, KEY_ID "= userid", null);

}
```

What should i do in this to correct it inwhereClause and whereArgs?

> return db.update(TABLE_LOGIN, values, whereClause, whereArgs);

do it possible to use KEY_EMAIL = KEY_EMAIL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
return db.update(TABLE_LOGIN, values, KEY_ID "= userid", null);
```

with something like

```
return db.update(TABLE_LOGIN, values, KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[] { userid });
```

Use `+` to concatenate strings.

`?` is a placeholder for a literal and they are bound from the whereArgs array.

`userid` in SQL without `'single quotes'` is taken as an identifier (column name) and not as a string literal. Hence you get an error like "no such column: userid".

Additionally, change the `void` in your method signature to `int` if you want to return a value from the method.

Comment: but having problem with this `Multiple markers at this line
 - Void methods cannot return a value
 - Syntax error on token ""= ?"", delete 
  this token`